# Creating dynamic password master file in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a password master file that will dynamically password protect a file based on column G and H.

My master file.
[image]

```vb
Public Sub addPassword()
Dim FSO As Object
Dim folder As Object, subfolder As Object
Dim wb As Object
   
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
folderPath = ActiveSheet.Range("H2:H11").Value
pwd = ActiveSheet.Range("G2:G11").Value
Set folder = FSO.GetFolder(folderPath)

With Application
    .DisplayAlerts = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
    .AskToUpdateLinks = False
End With
    
For Each wb In folder.Files
    If Right(wb.Name, 3) = "xls" Or Right(wb.Name, 4) = "xlsx" Or Right(wb.Name, 4) = "xlsm" Then
        Set masterWB = Workbooks.Open(wb)
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName, Password:=pwd
        ActiveWorkbook.Close True
    End If
Next
For Each subfolder In folder.SubFolders
    For Each wb In subfolder.Files
        If Right(wb.Name, 3) = "xls" Or Right(wb.Name, 4) = "xlsx" Or Right(wb.Name, 4) = "xlsm" Then
            Set masterWB = Workbooks.Open(wb)
            ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName, Password:=pwd
            ActiveWorkbook.Close True
        End If
    Next
Next
With Application
    .DisplayAlerts = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    .AskToUpdateLinks = True
End With
End Sub
```

The error I'm getting is that the path is incorrect "Set folder = FSO.GetFolder(folderPath)" and the type is a mismatch.

I ensured the reference for scripting runtime is selected like so
[image]

I am also not sure if the range I specified is correct for the password and folder

```
folderPath = ActiveSheet.Range("H2:H11").Value
pwd = ActiveSheet.Range("G2:G11").Value
```

I would like to click on the add password button to assign the password in column G to the file in column H. The files are in one folder.

Comment: Wouldn't `folderPath = ActiveSheet.Range("H2:H11").Value` technically be 10 different paths(files)?  Very hard for `FSO.GetFolder` to know what you mean in this case. `folderPath = ActiveSheet.Range("H2").Value` should work however.

Comment: Likewise `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName, Password:=pwd`will have a hard time to know which of all the passwords you want to use. You might want to store it in an array, and iterate through that.

Comment: Hi Christofer. Thanks for replying. Yes folderPath = ActiveSheet.Range("H2").Value does work but I have a 1000 files that I need to password protect for users. Any idea how i could create an array that will loop through each file path and assign the password to it ? Apologies for any silly questions.. I am very new to VBA.

Comment: Well, in this example, you only have one folder path. Then you loop through all the files with your loops anyway. So as long as there aren't different folders... But then we still have the issue of matching the password to the right file. So I think you need a different approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your example, we are already using an absolute reference to the sheet, and full path in the cell.
So we should be able to make it pretty short.
Added a check that the cell isn't empty, and that the file exists. Otherwise those scenarios will throw an error:

```vb
Public Sub addPassword()
Dim documents As Range, wb As Range

Set documents = ActiveSheet.Range("H2:H11")

With Application
    .DisplayAlerts = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
    .AskToUpdateLinks = False
End With

For Each wb In documents
    If Not wb.Value = "" Then
        If Not Dir(wb.Value) = "" Then
            Set masterWB = Workbooks.Open(wb)
            ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName, Password:=wb.Offset(, -1)
            ActiveWorkbook.Close True
        End If
    End If
Next

With Application
    .DisplayAlerts = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    .AskToUpdateLinks = True
End With

End Sub
```

If you don't have every file name, you could technically use your initial approach, that takes a path and just loops through every file there, and in all the subfolders. This would mean a single password for each "main" folder.
This would in your example however, cause the macro to loop the same folder 10 times, since all the links are to the same folder.

One way to do it, would be using Application.Transpose() to make a 1D array when assigning the range to the variable.
And then looping through all the values of the array.

I ended up putting in some extra things:
`If Not folderPath(i) = "" Then` to not throw an error if the cell in `H` is empty
`fileName` to later in `Set folder = FSO.GetFolder()` remove the file name from the path. Because it was causing issues for me.

```vb
Public Sub addPassword()
Dim FSO As Object
Dim folder As Object, subfolder As Object
Dim wb As Object
Dim folderPath As Variant
Dim fileName As Variant
Dim pwd As Variant


Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
folderPath = Application.Transpose(ActiveSheet.Range("H2:H11"))
fileName = Application.Transpose(ActiveSheet.Range("F2:F11"))
pwd = Application.Transpose(ActiveSheet.Range("G2:G11"))


With Application
    .DisplayAlerts = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
    .AskToUpdateLinks = False
End With
  
For i = LBound(folderPath) To UBound(folderPath)
    If Not folderPath(i) = "" Then
        Set folder = FSO.GetFolder(Left(folderPath(i), Len(folderPath(i)) - Len(fileName(i))))
            For Each wb In folder.Files
                If Right(wb.Name, 3) = "xls" Or Right(wb.Name, 4) = "xlsx" Or Right(wb.Name, 4) = "xlsm" Then
                    Set masterWB = Workbooks.Open(wb)
                    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:=Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName, Password:=pwd(i)
                    ActiveWorkbook.Close True
                End If
            Next
        For Each subfolder In folder.SubFolders
            For Each wb In subfolder.Files
                If Right(wb.Name, 3) = "xls" Or Right(wb.Name, 4) = "xlsx" Or Right(wb.Name, 4) = "xlsm" Then
                    Set masterWB = Workbooks.Open(wb)
                    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:=Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName, Password:=pwd(i)
                    ActiveWorkbook.Close True
                End If
            Next
        Next
    End If
Next
With Application
    .DisplayAlerts = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    .AskToUpdateLinks = True
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Christofer. This solution is exactly what i needed. I dont need the subfolder so i just removed that part. Fantastic solution.